# Mysql result order by sum()

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have to tables:(`id`,`name`) and another table (`id`,`id_name`,`money`).

In the second table I have something like that:

```
1, 1, 200
2, 1, 400
3, 2, 400
```

In the first table :

```
1,alex
2,jason
```

After I execute the query I want to receive this result :

```
alex,600

jason,400
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT tabel1.nume ,SUM(tabel2.money) FROM tabel2 JOIN tabel2 
    ON tabel1.id = tabel2.id_name
WHERE tabel1.id = tabel2.id_name ORDER BY SUM(money)
```

I receive just the first row from the second table.

WHere I do the mistake ??

Comment: Can you add titles to the tables in your question

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT tabel1.name ,SUM(tabel2.money) 
 FROM tabel2 JOIN tabel2 ON tabel1.id = tabel2.id_name
 WHERE tabel1.id = tabel2.id_name 
GROUP BY tabel1.name
ORDER BY SUM(money)
```

If you use aggregate functions without `GROUP BY`, MySQL will group everything into single row.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use group by when you use aggregate functions, using aggregate functions without grouping them will result in a single row by assuming the whole table as one group,according to your desired result set you also need `DESC` after ORDER BY clause

```
SELECT tabel1.id,
tabel1.nume ,
SUM(tabel2.money) `sum_money`
FROM tabel2 
JOIN tabel2 ON tabel1.id = tabel2.id_name 
GROUP BY tabel1.id
ORDER BY sum_money DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
tabel1.nume,
SUM(tabel2.money) 
FROM tabel2 
JOIN tabel2 ON tabel1.id = tabel2.id_name
GROUP BY tabel1.nume
ORDER BY SUM(money)
```

You don't need to use where cluase here, you are doing this already on `JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `Group By` in there

```
SELECT tabel1.id, tabel1.nume, SUM(tabel2.money) `sum_money`
FROM tabel2 JOIN tabel2 ON tabel1.id = tabel2.id_name
WHERE tabel1.id = tabel2.id_name 
GROUP BY tabel1.id
ORDER BY sum_money
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, look at your first line of the query:

```
  SELECT tabel1.nume ,SUM(tabel2.money) FROM tabel2 JOIN tabel2
```

Unless you don't have column titled 'nume' in your first table, this tabel1.nume seems to be a typo, hence creating troubles. Besides, you are selecting from tabel2, joining with tabel2. This is wrong, you need to join with tabel1 instead of tabel2.

Secondly, consider your third line in the query:

```
  WHERE tabel1.id = tabel2.id_name
```

You don't actually need to put a **WHERE** clause here, since you are performing a join between tabel1 and tabel2 and so, you're using this line:

```
  ON tabel1.id = tabel2.id_name
```

Which actually substitutes the **WHERE** clause.

Thirdly, you need to use a **GROUP BY** clause in accordance with your tabel1.id. If you use **GROUP BY**, you no longer need to use **ORDER BY**.

To sum up, now your corrected query should look like this:

```
  SELECT tabel1.name ,SUM(tabel2.money) FROM tabel2 JOIN tabel1 
  ON tabel2.id_name = tabel1.id
  GROUP BY tabel1.id
```

Hope this answered your question.